# useEffect is causing error because of variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just finished a project in react. But the only error that I couldn't solve was the function below:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (guessedLetters.length 
            === uniqueLetters.length){
            
            startGame({ 
                score: score + points 
            })
        }
    }, [guessedLetters.length])
```

Error: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'points', 'score', 'startGame', and 'uniqueLetters.length'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: [guessedLetters.length, points, score, startGame]  you can include it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to resolve this issue. But there maybe side-effects due to this. Side-effects include unnecessary re-rendering or no rendering at all.

First: Make the dependency array empty.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (guessedLetters.length 
            === uniqueLetters.length){
            
            startGame({ 
                score: score + points 
            })
        }
    }, [])
```

Second: Include all the variables that you have used inside the use Effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (guessedLetters.length 
            === uniqueLetters.length){
            
            startGame({ 
                score: score + points 
            })
        }
    }, [guessedLetters.length, uniqueLetters.length, points, score, startGame])
```

Alternatively, you can also use useCallback hook.

Comment: Your answer was very complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (guessedLetters.length 
            === uniqueLetters.length){
            
            startGame({ 
                score: score + points 
            })
        }
    }, [guessedLetters.length, points, score, startGame, uniqueLetters.length])
```

will get rid of the warnings, but you probably have a problem in the way your app mechanics are built if you're depending on so much stuff for the useEffect, the simple fact of adding the deps will probably introduce new bugs